# Entity Framework - printing EntityValidationErrors to log

Tags: c#, entity-framework, logging, entity-framework-4

I get the follo0wing error when I print my log

```
Message: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors'  
property for more details.; Stack Trace:    at 
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
```

The EntityValidationErrors object holds the full detailed error in different nodes.
What is the best way to print it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

cleaner syntax:

```
catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
     Logger.WriteError("{0}{1}Validation errors:{1}{2}", ex, Environment.NewLine, ex.EntityValidationErrors.Select(e => string.Join(Environment.NewLine, e.ValidationErrors.Select(v => string.Format("{0} - {1}", v.PropertyName, v.ErrorMessage)))));
     throw;
}
```

Comment: perfect, and if you have just had the exception and want to see it in the immediate window, you can use "$exception" so:    $exception.EntityValidationErrors.Select(e => string.Join(Environment.NewLine, e.ValidationErrors.Select(v => string.Format("{0} - {1}", v.PropertyName, v.ErrorMessage))))

Answer (score 26):

### Here are some extension methods:

```
/// <summary>
///     A DbEntityValidationException extension method that formates validation errors to string.
/// </summary>
public static string DbEntityValidationExceptionToString(this DbEntityValidationException e)
{
    var validationErrors = e.DbEntityValidationResultToString();
    var exceptionMessage = string.Format("{0}{1}Validation errors:{1}{2}", e, Environment.NewLine, validationErrors);
    return exceptionMessage;
}

/// <summary>
///     A DbEntityValidationException extension method that aggregate database entity validation results to string.
/// </summary>
public static string DbEntityValidationResultToString(this DbEntityValidationException e)
{
    return e.EntityValidationErrors
            .Select(dbEntityValidationResult => dbEntityValidationResult.DbValidationErrorsToString(dbEntityValidationResult.ValidationErrors))
            .Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, next) => string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", current, Environment.NewLine, next));
}

/// <summary>
///     A DbEntityValidationResult extension method that to strings database validation errors.
/// </summary>
public static string DbValidationErrorsToString(this DbEntityValidationResult dbEntityValidationResult, IEnumerable<DbValidationError> dbValidationErrors)
{
    var entityName = string.Format("[{0}]", dbEntityValidationResult.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name);
    const string indentation = "\t - ";
    var aggregatedValidationErrorMessages = dbValidationErrors.Select(error => string.Format("[{0} - {1}]", error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage))
                                           .Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, validationErrorMessage) => current + (Environment.NewLine + indentation + validationErrorMessage));
    return string.Format("{0}{1}", entityName, aggregatedValidationErrorMessages);
}
```

**Usecase 1:**

```
catch(DbEntityValidationException e) {
    Logger.WriteError(e.DbEntityValidationExceptionToString());
    throw;      
}
```

Should Output:

```
StackTrace
Validation errores:
[EntityName]
    - [Property - ErrorMessage]
    - [Property - ErrorMessage]
[EntityName2]
    - [Property - ErrorMessage]
    - [Property - ErrorMessage]
```

**Usecase 2:**

```
catch(DbEntityValidationException e) {
    Logger.WriteError(e.DbEntityValidationResultToString());
    throw;      
}
```

Should Output:

```
[EntityName]
    - [Property - ErrorMessage]
    - [Property - ErrorMessage]
[EntityName2]
    - [Property - ErrorMessage]
    - [Property - ErrorMessage]
```

Comment: In which namespace does Logger reside? I am unable to find the WriteError method in the built-in logger class

Comment: @shivisuper it is just an example and not part of the extension code, it just shows you how you may use the extension code... Switch out `Logger.WriteError` with `Console.WriteLine` for a console app and so on...

Comment: @furier oh I get it, my bad

Answer (score 8):

You can try something like this

```
   foreach (var failure in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
       string validationErrors="";

        foreach (var error in failure.ValidationErrors)
        {
           validationErrors+=error.PropertyName+"  "+error.ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: put the code above into a try catch - try {...} catch(Exception ex) {...}

Comment: Downvote for not using StringBuilder. String concat in a loop is dangerous practice.

Comment: Dangerous? At worst is not performant... and as it is in a try catch (a costy operation) it doesn't matter.